# calc in linear gradient does not work in IE/Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, linear-gradients

IE and Edge do not seem to be able to calculate the height correctly in this gradient. Does anyone have a solution?

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100px, #f5f5f5 100px, #f5f5f5 calc(100% - 100px), rgba(255,255,255,0) calc(100% - 100px));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as you are using a transparent "stripe", you can *cheat* by using **two** linear gradients both only going 50% of the height.

You start one from the top and the second from the bottom

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 100px, #f5f5f5 100px, #f5f5f5 50%, transparent 50%), 
    linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 100px, #f5f5f5 100px, #f5f5f5 50%, transparent 50%);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: pink; /* for demo purposes */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ALwowz?editors=0100#0)